# tfs:"File is exclusively checked out by another user" - which user?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, tfs

I use Team Foundation Server 2008 and cannot add a folder in a setup project. The error is that 6 files are "File is exclusively checked out by another user."

How can I see which user they are checked out to and when they were checked out?

I suspect it to be a former employee that worked on this project. Either that or my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Team Explorer double click 'Source Control'.

You will see a Source Control Explorer. Under your collection expand to the project of your interest. In the right pane your will see following columns: name, Pending change and User etc..

The User column, if not blank, shows the user the item is checked out to.

Comment: Excellent. I cannot unlock it, but I've been told it's because I don't have the permissions. So that job has been forwarded.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at TFS Sidekicks found at http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/

They have a Status Sidekick that tells you which files are checked out by whom. It's also possible to Undo the checkout (attention!)

Comment: Thank you. It actually says so in the Output window and it was to the former employee. I'm just blind.

Answer (score 3):

The command-line `tf.exe` can show you this:

```
tf status *.* /recursive /user:*
```

from an appropriate place will show you pending changes from all users to all files in the hierarchy below.

Comment: I did it from the command window in VS2008. It says Command "tf" is not valid. Any idea why?

Comment: @Kasper you'll need to make sure the folder containing `tf` is in your environment `PATH` setting. The 'Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt' shortcut that VS puts in your Start menu should set this up correctly.

Comment: @Kasper you can run this command from VS command prompt, but again as said above, the assumption is the path is set, which is likely for VS command prompt.